# What cvar or mod is required to increase max players in TF2 MvM

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration, tf2-mann-vs-machine

I have noticed that a few community MvM servers allow more than the default 6 players per team.  What cvar needs to be set or what mod needs to be installed on the server to set the max allowed players to a higher (or lower) number?

I would prefer setting a variable over a mod, but will go for a mod if there is no stock functionality for changing max team size.

Comment: fyi: increasing the number of player slots will decrease the amount of slots available to the machines. meaning the stock maps will become painfully easy.

Comment: this is true.  its more about letting the 7th guy participate than making it hard for the other 6. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mod that allows up to 10 players on an MvM team (9 if using Replay, 8 if using both Reply and SourceTV)

http://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=198384